# JUnit @After not executing when Jenkins pipeline is stopped

Tags: jenkins, junit, jenkins-pipeline, junit4, sigterm

I'm working with a declarative Jenkins pipeline that runs some tests which make use of JUnit 4. In the tests there are `@After` methods where test cleanup occurs. When a pipeline is aborted during a test I've confirmed that the `@After` methods are never executed (confirmed using log statements in the `@After` methods and checking the Jenkins console log).

This leaves test data (e.g. users that the tests use) in a bad state and cause later tests (and pipeline builds) to fail, so it's an issue.

The pipeline is aborted via the Jenkins UI "stop" button, or through the pipeline hitting a timeout for that stage. In both cases the pipeline exits with code 143, which is a `SIGTERM`.

How can I ensure that JUnit 4.x `@After` methods are executed when a declarative Jenkins pipeline is aborted?

Comment: In a similar position, we execute cleanup from Jenkinsfile both *before* and *after* running the tests. This ensures that no matter why the tests were stopped in the middle, the new set of tests starts with a clean environment.

Comment: Thanks @MaratC. Good idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a workaround that you could use to solve the issue. Create two classes. TestClass and AfterClass. In the AfterClass, you will have to keep one test method so that after will get triggered. Now, In test execution step of declarative pipeline, you can execute

```
mvn clean test -PTest
```

and in the post always of declarative pipeline script, you can execute below maven command

```
mvn clean test -PCleanup
```

**TestClass:**

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestClass 
{

    @Test
    public void testClass()
    {
        System.out.println("Test");
    }
}
```

**AfterClass:**

```
@Test
public void beforeCleanUp()
{
    System.out.println("Before Cleanup");
}
@After
public void after()
{
    System.out.println("After");
}
```

**POM.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>stackovrflw-62492859</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>Test</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <test>com.test.junit.classes.TestClass</test>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>Cleanup</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <test>com.test.junit.classes.AfterClass</test>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Note: This is not the actual solution as I do not have much experience on JUnit. But you could use this workaround, if you do not get any proper solution. I will be also trying to find proper solution for you